Stripe Webhook not working on AWS Lightsail Container
I’ve set up a Stripe webhook that works perfectly in my local environment, but it’s not functioning correctly after deploying my application on AWS Lightsail containers. Other API endpoints are working fine, and the application is served over HTTPS.
Could you help me troubleshoot why the webhook is not firing on the deployed environment? Are there any specific configuration requirements or best practices for webhook handling in AWS Lightsail containers?
Thank you!

You should visit your Stripe event Dashboard and check why the event wasn't delivered successfully. The common webhook problems are usually caused by incorrect webhook secret, or endpoint not responding 200 code in time. You can find more details about how to solve these problems on this page
